# How to partition single drive without losing data in it for Windows 7 

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I did not partition my hard disk at starting. Now i want make a partition for it, can you suggest to me a better way to do it without losing the data in it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're talking about here. You cannot install Windows without having a partition. Are you saying you want to shrink your existing partition and make a new one?

Answer (score 2):

Get yourself a linux liveCD.  Linux has partition tools that allow you to resize a partition without erasing it.

Or get Partition Magic.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the disk space use Shrink that is built in Win Vista/7.

If you can't even use or borrow a portable HDD and do what @surfasb says.