# How to make partition on my windows 7 laptop hdd without losing and moving current data?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to partition single drive without losing data in it for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/245543/how-to-partition-single-drive-without-losing-data-in-it-for-windows-7)

How to make partition on my laptop hdd without losing and moving current data?

When I received laptop there was no partition and windows and some software were installed.

Now without reinstalling windows, without losing any data can I make partition. my laptop HDD is 500GB and 400 GB is free.

I'm looking for any freeware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repartition your harddrive from within Windows 7 using the Shrink feature.  The MS kb article is at:  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Can-I-repartition-my-hard-disk

1. Go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management
2. Click Disk Management (it's under Storage)
3. Right-click the volume and then click Shrink Volume
4. Follow the Wizard

Comment: Is it safe to do?

Comment: As indicated by Sathya, this question has already been answered.  Look at http://superuser.com/questions/88131/how-to-shrink-windows-7-boot-partition-with-unmovable-files