# Can I Multiboot Without Having to Wipe My Drive and Reinstall All of My Programs

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, linux-mint, reinstall, osx-yosemite

I want to multiboot my PC with Windows 8.1, Yosemite, and Linux Mint, but I already have Windows 8.1 on my hard drive and lots of programs and files on it. To multiboot, do I have to wipe my hard drive and reinstall Windows 8.1 along with the other operating systems in the process? Is there a way that I can multiboot my PC without having to reinstall all of my programs and files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to partition single drive without losing data in it for Windows 7](http://superuser.com/q/245543/354511) or [How to shrink Windows 7 boot partition with unmovable files](http://superuser.com/q/88131/354511).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can shrink the partition with Windows 8.1, in order to provide enough space to install other operating systems. You'll want to make a backup copy of your Windows install, though, in case anything goes wrong. Something like [GNU Parted](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/) can do this, I believe, and will certainly be available on your Linux Mint installation media.

Note that you cannot legally install OSX except on Apple hardware. There are ways to bypass the restrictions, but even if you manage to get it to work, you shouldn't expect a particularly smooth experience.

Comment: Your answer is confusing, because the OP asks 2 questions a nd it isn't clear which one you are answering. )

Comment: Yeah. I didn't mention how to actually multiboot. That pretty much comes for free if you install Linux Mint alongside Windows. As to Yosemite, again, that's not supported except on Apple hardware.